# / in attachment names

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I've just started developing a web page with jquery mobile using couchdb and iriscouch as the database.

what i'd like to know is if i can get a / symbol in the attachment names? What i'd like to achieve is that i have one document which contains the HTML files as attachents and all the images and whatnot also as an attachments, but with the name image/testimage.jpg as its name. Windows ins't letting me name files with / in their name and I can't rename the attachments in futon after attaching them.

This is so that I can use the same html files that I already have and won't have to change the src's of all the images and other files i have in the HTML.

Is this even possible?

Comment: at what point does the attachment name get created?

Comment: Well im using futon to add attachments and those get created by using a regular looking upload dialog. it just takes the name of the file uploaded as the name of the attachment.

Comment: Have you tried creating attachments through code?

Comment: Yes I can create attachments with / in their name by using a quick hacked together python app, but the problem is with the workflow by using that, what i'd want is to just use futon to do the uploading and attaching of files, but does not seem possible. Maybe I'll just write a python script to go through the images folder and upload all the files with "images/" added to their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible as long as the `/` is properly URL encoded as `%2F`.

Comment: Yeah, seems like the problem is with futon and the inability to rename the attachments. The futon uploader should have a feature to let me change the attachment name when uploading files.

Comment: Answer was right, I can do attachements over the API, but not over futon.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the problem lies in the futon couchapp. It doenst handle the / in names properly, propably does not handle encoding or the / letter is denied, didn't check the sources, but when using the HTML Api i can do attachments with / in their name properly.

This allowed me to very easily port my HTML and JS files and source file s which were in folders to CouchDB. Another really helpful application is [CouchApp](http://couchapp.org/page/filesystem-mapping), which maps directory structures straight into couchDB and created attachements with / letter in their names.